# How to lock a partition with Ubuntu so that it won't be accidentally wiped during an OS installation?

Tags: command-line, partitioning, system-installation, lock, user-data

I want to install Arch. I have no use CLI-installer. So I am scared that I delete my important data in a partition. Can I lock the partition for saving data?
I use ubuntu. Can I do it in ubuntu?
Or is there a way to hide the partition from the installer?

Comment: I am not scared of cli os. Just I am scared of cli "installation". I edited the question. I use ubuntu and want to do that (lock the partition) in ubuntu.

Comment: (Thanks for the clarification. I have now upvoted the question.) I don't know how to lock a partition in Ubuntu but here is a suggestion. There are derivatives of Arch (e.g. Manjaro, Endeaveour OS) which provide a graphical installer, and after installation the experience is almost same as Arch (and you would also have a preinstalled GUI).

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Thank you for the comment and edit the question. I know about derivatives of arch and I have used Manjaro live, but for some reasons I want to install Arch.

Comment: I don't know how to lock a partition in Ubuntu. An installer is a very powerful tool, and is allowed to write 'anywhere' on a drive, so you must know what you are doing. The best method to preserve a drive (and the partitions on that drive) is to **disconnect or unplug the drive** before you install Ubuntu, Arch or some other operating system into another drive. You can also get a cheap old (but still working) computer for testing purposes.

Comment: @sudodus I don't use multiple drives. I have only one drive with some partitions. Can I disconnect or unplug one of them?

Comment: I don't know any way to lock, disconnect or unplug only a partition, but let the other parts of the drive to be written to by a linux installer.

Comment: There is no way to lock a partition that I know of. Use GParted to make a copy of the partition on another external device. When you install Arch just be careful with the device names. Add labels to each partition to make it easier to identify which is what. Installing Arch is not that hard but follow the instructions precisely.

Comment: Thank you all helpers!

Comment: Full Install Arch on a USB drive, (or spare HDD), and then use GParted to copy/paste that partition to free space on the Ubuntu disk. Update Ubuntu's GRUB to add Arch to Ubuntu's boot menu.